# Is "fuffa" the correct translation for "fluff"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, meaning, translation

I was given "fuffa" as translation for "fluff" and then while double-checking it using Google translator, I was shocked that it showed me "fuffa" as "crap".

The context it was used was:

> Ultimately, it’s difficult to separate the fluff 
>   Infine, è difficile separare la fuffa

By the way, is "fuffa" a bad word? (una parolaccia?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The translation of *fuffa* as *fluff* is correct, 
it is the typical unaesthetic fluff (or *lanugine* in Italian) that forms on cloth and that is generally removed.

Moreover it is not considered a bad word at all but just a colloquial term.

The term is also used figuratively to indicate something which is in excess and consequently useless, with no consistency.

In a document, for example, the *fuffa* is a large amount of words that are written just to increase its length, without adding relevant content or information to it.

In an informal or colloquial context we use the term *fuffarolo* to describe an expert of something that cannot be precisely described, someone who’s capable to say a lot of words without saying nothing.

Comment: When I lived in Pisa we used the word "fuffa" as synonym of "nonsense". I don't know if it was a regional usage or if so from which region (I hung around a fairly heterogeneous crowd)

Answer (score 9):

@abarisone gave you a good answer (though I never heard the word fuffarolo, maybe it’s regional). I want to add that fuffa is not a bad word and you can use it in any context (of course if you told someone all you’re saying is fuffa, he/she may not take it too well)

Comment: Thank you for the extra bit of info :) much appreciated! yes I wanted to know whether "fuffa" was a bad word per se, because Google translate was translating it to English as "crap".

Comment: "crap" is a bit too harsh as a translation IMO :) as pointed in the answer, "fuffa" has a figurative meaning similar to "with no consistency"